# Terraform s3 backend not used by module

Tags: terraform

I've begun working with Terraform and have totally bought into it - amazing! having created my entire Dev environment in terms of AWS VPC, subnets, NACLs, SGs, Route tables etc etc etc, I have decided that I had better turn this into reusable modules.

So now I have turned it into modules, with variables etc. Now my dev template simply takes variables and uses them as inputs to the module. I end up with this:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "redacted"
    key    = "dev/vpc/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "eu-west-1"
    encrypt = true
    dynamodb_table = "terraform_statelock_redacted"
  }
}

provider "aws"{
  access_key = ""
  secret_key = ""
  region     = "eu-west-1"
}

module "base_vpc" {
  source = "git@github.com:closed/terraform-modules.git//vpc"


  vpc_cidr = "${var.vpc_cidr}"
  vpc_region = "${var.vpc_region}"
  Environment = "${var.Environment}"
  Public-subnet-1a = "${var.Public-subnet-1a}"
  Public-subnet-1b = "${var.Public-subnet-1b}"
  Private-subnet-1a = "${var.Private-subnet-1a}"
  Private-subnet-1b = "${var.Private-subnet-1b}"
  Private-db-subnet-1a = "${var.Private-db-subnet-1a}"
  Private-db-subnet-1b = "${var.Private-db-subnet-1b}"
  Onsite-computers = "${var.Onsite-computers}"
  browse_access = "${var.browse_access}"
}
```

Now I have all state managed in an s3 backend, as you can see in the above configuration. I also have other state files for services/instances that are running. My problem is that now that I have turned this into a module and referenced it as above, it wants to blow away my state! I was under the impression that it would import the module and run it whilst respecting other configuration. The actual module code was copied from the original template, so nothing has changed there.

Is there a reason it is trying to blow everything away and start again? How does one manage separate states per environment in the case of using modules? I get no other errors. I have devs working on some of the servers at the moment so I'm paralysed now ha!

I guess I've misunderstood something, any help much appreciated :) 
Thanks. 
Edit - Using Terraform 0.9.8

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this issue and decided each environment needed a code representation we could view at the same time as the others if needed, ie compare dev configs to qa.

So now we have a folder for dev and one for qa and we launch terraform from there.  Each is basically a list of variables that calls modules for each component.

Here is my tree for a visual representation

```
$ tree terraform/
terraform/
├── api_gateway
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── database
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── dev
│   └── main.tf
├── ec2
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── kms
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── network
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── output.tf
│   └── variables.tf
├── qa
│   └── main.tf
└── sns
    ├── output.tf
    ├── main.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

`dev/main.tf` and `qa/main.tf` import the modules provided by the other folders supplying environment specific configurations for each module.

EDIT: here is a sanitized version of my `dev/main.tf`

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  profile = "blah-dev"
  shared_credentials_file = "${pathexpand("~/.aws/credentials")}"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "sweet-dev-bucket"
    key = "sweet/dev.terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
    profile = "blah-dev"
  }
}

variable "aws_account" {
  default = "000000000000"
}
variable "env" {
  default = "dev"
}
variable "aws_region" {
  default = "us-east-1"
}
variable "tag_product" {
  default = "sweet"
}
variable "tag_business_region" {
  default = "east"
}
variable "tag_business_unit" {
  default = "my-department"
}
variable "tag_client" {
  default = "some-client"
}

module build_env {
  source = "../datasources"
}

module "kms" {
  source = "../kms"
  tag_client = "${var.tag_client}"
  tag_business_region = "${var.tag_business_region}"
  tag_business_unit = "${var.tag_business_unit}"
  tag_product = "${var.tag_product}"
}

module "network" {
  source = "../network"
  vpc_id = "vpc-000a0000"
  subnet_external_1B = "subnet-000a0000"
  subnet_external_1D = "subnet-000a0001"
  subnet_db_1A = "subnet-000a0002"
  subnet_db_1B = "subnet-000a0003"
}

module "database" {
  source = "../database"
  env = "dev"
  vpc_id = "${module.network.vpc_id}"
  subnet_external_1B = "${module.network.subnet_external_1B}"
  subnet_external_1D = "${module.network.subnet_external_1D}"
  subnet_db_1A = "${module.network.subnet_db_1A}"
  subnet_db_1B = "${module.network.subnet_db_1B}"
  database_instance_size = "db.t2.small"
  database_name = "my-${var.tag_product}-db"
  database_user_name = "${var.tag_product}"
  database_passwd = "${module.kms.passwd_plaintext}"
  database_identifier = "${var.tag_product}-rds-database"
  database_max_connections = "150"
}

module sns {
  source = "../sns"
  aws_account = "${var.aws_account}"
}

module "api_gateway" {
  source = "../api_gateway"
  env = "${var.env}"
  vpc_id = "${module.network.vpc_id}"
  domain_name = "${var.tag_product}-dev.example.com"
  dev_certificate_arn = "arn:aws:acm:${var.aws_region}:${var.aws_account}:certificate/abcd0000-a000-a000-a000-1234567890ab"
  aws_account = "${var.aws_account}"
  aws_region = "${var.aws_region}"
  tag_client = "${var.tag_client}"
  tag_business_unit = "${var.tag_business_unit}"
  tag_product = "${var.tag_product}"
  tag_business_region = "${var.tag_business_region}"
  autoscaling_events_sns_topic_arn = "${module.sns.sns_topic_arn}"
  db_subnet_id_1 = "${module.network.subnet_db_1A}"
  db_subnet_id_2 = "${module.network.subnet_db_1B}"
  ec2_role = "${var.tag_product}-assume-iam-role"
  kms_key_arn = "${module.kms.kms_arn}"
  passwd_cypher_text = "${module.kms.passwd_cyphertext}"
}

module "ec2" {
  source = "../ec2"
  s3_bucket = "${var.tag_product}_dev_bucket"
  aws_region = "${var.aws_region}"
  env = "${var.env}"
  ec2_key_name = "my-${var.tag_product}-key"
  ec2_instance_type = "t2.micro"
  aws_account = "${var.aws_account}"
  vpc_id = "${module.network.vpc_id}"
  binary_path = "${module.build_env.binary_path}"
  binary_hash = "${module.build_env.binary_hash}"
  git_hash_short = "${module.build_env.git_hash_short}"
  private_key = "${format("%s/keys/%s-%s.pem", path.root, var.tag_product, var.env)}"
  cloudfront_domain = "${module.api_gateway.cloudfront_domain}"
  api_gateway_domain = "${module.api_gateway.api_gateway_cname}"
  tag_client = "${var.tag_client}"
  tag_business_region = "${var.tag_business_region}"
  tag_product = "${var.tag_product}"
  tag_business_unit = "${var.tag_business_unit}"
  auto_scale_desired_capacity = "1"
  auto_scale_max = "2"
  auto_scale_min = "1"
  autoscaling_events_sns_topic = "${module.sns.sns_topic_arn}"
  subnet_external_b = "${module.network.subnet_external_b}"
  subnet_external_a = "${module.network.subnet_external_a}"
  kms_key_arn = "${module.kms.kms_arn}"
  passwd_cypher_text = "${module.kms.passwd_cyphertext}"
}
```

Then my QA is basically the same (modify a couple vars at the top) however the most important difference is the very top of the `qa/main.tf`  Mostly these vars:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  profile = "blah-qa"
  shared_credentials_file = "${pathexpand("~/.aws/credentials")}"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "sweet-qa-bucket"
    key = "sweet/qa.terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
    profile = "blah-qa"
  }
}

variable "aws_account" {
  default = "000000000001"
}
variable "env" {
  default = "qa"
}
```

Using this our backend for `dev` and `qa` have different state files in different buckets in different aws accounts.  Idk what your requirements are but this has satisfied most projects I've worked with, in fact we are expanding our usage of this model across my org.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. So I'm trying to follow a very similar model, where the /dev, /test and /prod folders will basically just be calling a bunch of modules. The bit I'm stuck with is that I am holding the s3 backend configurations in those folders and it seems that using modules means that they are treating the existing state as no longer needed, i.e. marking them for destroy, then re-provisioning everything. Is there any chance you could share a redacted version of your dev.tf to show how you're managing the backend?

Comment: @TomNorth updated with my `dev/main.tf` and the main differences to show what changes for `qa/main.tf`.  This keeps a good separation where your state files are totally isolated and avoids tearing down dev when you create qa

Answer (score 1):

OK so I think the bit I misunderstood was the way that using modules changes the paths in the state file. I realised I was on the right line while reading the Terraform docs around state migration.

I found this great blog entry to assist me with getting my head around it:
https://ryaneschinger.com/blog/terraform-state-move/

No comment section for me to thank that guy! Anyway, after seeing how easy it was, I just output the `terraform state list` command to a text file for the main file. Used PowerShell to quickly iterate over these and write up the commands for the module I was moving them into. When I tried to execute the lines with this script I got the "Terraform has crashed!!!!" error, so just cut and paste them into my shell one by one. Proper nooby, but there was only 50 or so resources, so not that time consuming. SO glad I'm doing this at Dev stage rather than deciding to do it retrospectively in prod.

So I'm sorted. Thanks for your input though JBirdVegas.